# ORA-00911: invalid character with multiple select in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I get an error in `OracleCommand` vb.net:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

```
Using myCommand As New OracleCommand(
        "SELECT VAL2 FROM PARM WHERE ID BETWEEN 9900029 AND 9900033;" &
        "SELECT VAL4 FROM PARM WHERE ID = 9900030", DBSettings.GetConnection())
```

But this request works in `PL/SQL`.

Comment: What's about that semicolon? Here `AND 9900033;`. Try after removing it.

Comment: Could it be `;` that's causing the issue? Is this supported in Oracle?

Comment: @JSapkota ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. I have tried this before. I need to combine these two queries

Comment: You probably can't send more then one statement in a single call - at least that's the case in Java and I think that's a server side limitation, so it will most probably apply to vb.net as well. If you **have** to do that in a single call combine the two queries with a `union all` and just send a single statement

Comment: @Bugs I'm already ashamed in front of you. Yes, I think it semikolon, but anyway I must somehow combine these two requests. I think the problem is in the syntax, but found the answer to this question

Comment: @EmmaW. don't be ashamed :) The `;` is valid syntax in most SQL and probably Oracle however I've never used Oracle. It could be that this isn't how to execute two commands together using an `OracleCommand`. It could be worth just sending two separate commands. I think there is an ability to send transactions but not sure if it would work in this case.

Comment: Out of curiosity and I have _no_ idea if this will work but try adding `BEGIN` and `END` to your statements. So `BEGIN SELECT VAL2 FROM PARM WHERE ID BETWEEN 9900029 AND 9900033; END` and  `BEGIN SELECT VAL4 FROM PARM WHERE ID = 9900030; END`. Failing that, use a `UNION ALL` as suggested above.

Comment: @Bugs I used `BEGIN` and `END`, I have used all. Yes, I think I'll do it with the help of `UNION ALL`

Comment: `BEGIN` and `END` will not do any good here; they make it an anonymous PL/SQL block but you cannot simply put `SELECT` statements there and expect to somehow get the result sets returned - it doesn't work like that in Oracle.

Comment: @Bugs well, it works with `union all`. I can note your answer correct. It could be applied still yesterday, as proposed by the the_lotus

Comment: It was @a_horse_with_no_name that gave that answer regarding `UNION ALL` further up however yes definitely look into upvoting/marking as accepted `the_lotus'` answer on your previous question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank's a lot. It works with union all. I can note your answer :)

Comment: @Bugs yes, I did it :) I think I'm finally finished with this task. And about the properties, it took me about 2 hours to find out what my company wants :) For me it was a bit strange, so do not be surprised that you do not understand the work of this database

Comment: @ammoQ I've just seen your comment. Thanks for the heads up. I didn't think it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a query with **`UNION ALL`**:

```
"SELECT VAL2 FROM PARM WHERE ID BETWEEN 9900029 AND 9900033
UNION ALL
SELECT VAL4 FROM PARM WHERE ID = 9900030"
```

Comment: A 'try this' answer is always seen as low-quality answer. Either you know the solution for a problem or not. If not it's not appropriate to post a answer. You risk getting downvoted and other may fall over your false-positive answer.

Comment: If you are sure this really solves the issue, I am happy about it.